# Antlr how to escape quote symbol in quoted string

Tags: java, antlr

I want some grammar to represent a string, quoted by " and the " symbol inside string can be quoted like \". Following is my grammar:

```
fragment
NUM_LETTER : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9');

STRING_LITERAL : '"' (NUM_LETTER|'_'|('\\"'))* '"';
```

But it does not work. I try to interpret "\"a" in AntlrWorks1.5 and it gives a MismatchedTokenException in the generated syntax tree for STRING_LITERAL. Which part of my grammar is wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the grammar. You're probably getting this error because you're using the interpreter, which is buggy. Use ANTLRWorks' debugger instead. The debugger will show you the input `"\"a"` is parsed just fine (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to start debugging).

Also, your string rule would probably be better of looking like this:

```
STRING_LITERAL : '"' (~('"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n') | '\\' ('"' | '\\'))* '"';
```

In other words, the contents of your string is zero or more:

- any char other than a quote, backslash or line break: `~('"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n')`

or

- an escaped quote or backslash `'\\' ('"' | '\\')`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following expression:

```
STRING : '"' (options{greedy=false;}:( ~('\\'|'"') | ('\\' '"')))* '"';
```

Comment: Thanks Aubin. I added this "(options{greedy=false;}" part in my grammar and it worked. But how does antlr's greedy matching lead to the failure of my original expression?

Comment: You can remove the `options{greedy=false;}:` part.

Comment: @Ryan, it doesn't. The interpreter is a bit buggy.